# How to pipe opencv output from python to vlc

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, stream, vlc

Hello i want to send an opencv output web page via pipe.
When i use this command i get the video properly .

`python myscript.py | vlc --demux=rawvideo --rawvid-fps=25 --rawvid-width=640 --rawvid-height=480 --rawvid-chroma=RV24 - --sout "#display"`

I tried many options and with this one, no error but i get an empty frame:

`script.py | vlc --demux=rawvideo --rawvid-fps=10 --rawvid-width=640 --rawvid-height=480 --rawvid-chroma=RV24 - --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,fps=8{vcodec=h264,vb=200,fps=8,width=640,height=480}}:standard{access=http{mime="video/MP4T"},mux=ts,dst=127.0.0.1:5555}'`

I don't know how to get the good result.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it s laggy on my laptop but it works:

```
python script.py | ffmpeg -r 8 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s 640x480 -i - -c:v libx264 -f matroska  -listen 1 tcp://0.0.0.0:1234
```

I will send output to flask web page, it will be better.
Thank s